# jupyter anaconda 2.4 not trusting notebook

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to open an ipython notebook I have explicitly trusted using 
    jupyter trust "my\notebook\path\here.ipynb"
but when I try to open the notebook I get the error messsage:
    Notebook "my\notebook\path\here.ipynb" is not trusted

I am using Anaconda 2.4, clean install a few week ago.

Thoughts?

Comment: What exactly did you do? `ipython trust *.ipynb` should work